# How to display data in the instance to which I want to edit?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to edit the information in an instance of a crud, but at the time of doing so, it does not show me the information, which I had previously put in the create view and I do not understand how to show it, I have tried with the arguments 'form': form.cleane_data , 'form': form, but still does not show me the data that is in the fields, but that can be previously seen in a list view, which I have in the home of the application.

this is my funtion in views.py

```
def update_permisos(request, pk):
    p = get_object_or_404(permiso, pk=pk)
    form = permiForm(request.POST, instance=p)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():    
        if form.is_valid():
            permiso = form.save(commit=False)
            permiso.usuario = request.user
            permiso.save()
            permiso.usuario.status = request.POST['status':'Aceptado']
            permiso.usuario.d_pendientes = request.POST['d_pendientes']#valores, que van al campo
            permiso.usuario.h_pendientes = request.POST['h_pendientes']#valores, que van al campo
            permiso.usuario.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'true', 'msg':'Datos procesados correctamente'})#retornando JSon en jsConsole 
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'false', 'msg':'Datos procesados incorrectamente'})#retornando respuesta en jsConsole
    else:
        form = permiForm(instance=p)
        return render(request, 'plantillas/permisos.html')
```

this is my forms.py

```
class permiForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

    model = permiso

    fields = [

        'disponer',
        'razon',
        'periodo_i',
        'periodo_f',
        'dias_disponer',
        'horas_disponer',
        ]
```

if somebody, want see some other part of me code, tell me and i post it

Comment: Your form is for the model `permiso`, not the model `User`, so you should pass an instance of `permiso` not `request.user`. And `{'form': form}` is how you pass it into your context. Not `form.data`.

Comment: Are you planning to get something like placeholder in html fields? If so, you can add placeholder using `attrs={'placeholder': 'value_to_be_displayed'}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: Hi bro @dirkgroten with {'form':form}, i see the empyty fields, dont show data, i have already tried so

Comment: @JayVasant No bro, I want to show the data of an instance through my crud, to modify it.

Comment: @Jonathan I told you: first pass the correct instance to your form (not request.user). You won't see filled fields if you pass request.user as instance.

Comment: @dirkgroten ahh ok, 
Ok look at my view now. But now I get this error: local variable 'permiso' referenced before assignment

Comment: you should show the entire stack trace. But this is probably related to the fact that your model is `permiso` and you also call your instance `permiso` (so you're redefining the class). So always use python conventions: your class should be `Permiso` not `permiso` to avoid this kind of conflict.

Comment: @dirkgroten I changed the variable, but it still shows me the same error T.T, look my code, updated it

Comment: Did you import `permiso` (the model)? Just look at the line of your code where the error is pointing to. "local variable referenced before assignment" means you're using a symbol that isn't defined yet. Usually a missing import or some mistyping or some wrong logic.